# Command "tree" vs "tree -R"

Tags: linux, recursive, tree

So I'm asking myself why there is the "-R" argument for the "tree" command.

The manual says "-R Recursively cross down the tree each level directories ...", but I don't see any difference in the result between those two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-R` option is only effective in HTML output mode, and is ignored if you don’t also specify a maximum display depth with the `-L` option.

```
tree -R -L 2 -H . -o tree.html
```

will output the tree to `tree.html`, and additionally generate subtrees every two levels in `OOTree.thml` files in each corresponding directory.